# Rspec let(:model) + model.reload doesn't reload the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

```
let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }

it "should blah" do
  product.name = "a"
  product.save!
  post :update, id: product.id, product: { name: "x" }
  # assuming :update changes the product's name to params[:name]
  product.reload.name.should == "x"
end
```

The `should` always fails unless I do something like

```
Product.find(product.id).name.should == "x"
```

Am I misusing `let`?

If I work with `@product` created within `before :each` and `@product.reload` it's fine.

Comment: This is weird. You're not misusing `let` - it should work as you expect.

Is this the actual spec that causes the actual problem? I assume not. If so, can you please provide it, since the problem can be a bit intricate.

Comment: How does your products controller know which product instance to update? Does it grab the last one created? Is it possible there are already products in the db and factory girl creates one that isn't the last of the list?

Comment: This might not be the EXACT code but it's very similar (changed model name and attribute name). It's pretty consistent with all models...

Comment: i faced this problem as well. took almost half of an hour to realize it.

Answer (score 2):

If you break during execution of a spec and call `self.class.method(:let).source`, you get something like:

```
def let(name, &block)
  define_method(name) do
    __memoized.fetch(name) {|k| __memoized[k] = instance_eval(&block) }
  end
end
```

Upon further inspection, `__memoized` is just a simple Hash.  I don't think there's anything fancy going on here.  What precise versions of rails and rspec were you using?

Comment: this was very interesting